# Windows Phone 8.1 Custom Media Player

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, custom-controls, media-player, mediaelement

Good Day,

I am creating an app in which Media Player is needed. I tried using AreTransportControlsEnabled but it is a bit laggy which is I dont want. On my windows phone I have an app "Files"<-(An Application in Windows Phone 8.1) I use it to play one of my video and I saw its Video Player. I am thinking if I can achieve this kind of Player. Any suggestion how to achieve this Player?

picture: http://s22.postimg.org/plu0oqxv5/wp_ss_20150329_0002.png

I tried making a custom controls, but when on Fullscreen the controls doesnt shows up. Is there an api or something to do this?

---

**Question Answered**

My Custom MediaPlayer

Main Page.xalm

```
<Page
x:Class="MediaPlayer.MainPage"
IsTabStop="false"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MediaPlayer"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
Loaded="MainPage_Loaded">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="transportStyle"  TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
    </Style>
    <Thickness x:Key="PhoneBorderThickness">2.5</Thickness>
    <FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilyNormal">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
    <FontWeight x:Key="PhoneButtonFontWeight">Semibold</FontWeight>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextStyleLargeFontSize">18.14</x:Double>

    <x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinHeight">0</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinWidth">0</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="PhoneTouchTargetOverhang">0,0</Thickness>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
    <Style x:Key="RoundButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonFontWeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="9.5,0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path Stretch="Uniform"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              Margin="2,6,2,2"
              Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
              Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"></Path>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="PointerOver" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{ThemeResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Height="{Binding Path=Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Width="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" CornerRadius="72">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <!--<RowDefinition Height="150"/>-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl x:Name="videoContainer" 
                        KeyUp="VideoContainer_KeyUp" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        Grid.Row="0" >
        <MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement"
                          Source="Media/video1.mp4" 
                          MediaOpened="videoElement_MediaOpened" 
                          MediaEnded="videoMediaElement_MediaEnded" 
                          MediaFailed="videoMediaElement_MediaFailed"
                          CurrentStateChanged="videoMediaElement_CurrentStateChanged"
                          PosterSource="Media/Video1_Poster.png" PointerPressed="videoMediaElement_PointerPressed" />
    </ContentControl>
    <!-- Transport Controls -->
    <StackPanel Name="TransportControlsPanel" 
                Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#CC000000" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,15,0,0">
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnReverse_Click"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonStyle}" Height="72" Width="72" Content="M13.862404,0L17.667,3.8059161 10.879305,10.593651 17.6241,17.568752 13.861103,21.333 3.1840002,10.678149z M0,0L3.0719999,0 3.0719999,21.032 0,21.032z" Padding="20,5" Margin="20,0" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFE6E6E6"/>
            <Button x:Name="Play1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnPlay_Click"     VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonStyle}" Height="72" Width="72" Content="M27.270001,0L44.310001,0 44.310001,48.643002 27.270001,48.643002z M0,0L17.040001,0 17.040001,48.643002 0,48.643002z" Padding="20,10" Margin="20,0" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFE6E6E6"/>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnForward_Click"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonStyle}" Height="72" Width="72" Content="M14.595,0L17.668,0 17.668,21.032 14.595,21.032z M3.8059254,0L14.484001,10.67815 3.8059254,21.333 0.04431057,17.568752 6.7875929,10.593651 0,3.8059165z" Padding="20,5" Margin="20,0" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFE6E6E6"/>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnFullScreenToggle_Click"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonStyle}" Height="72" Width="72" Content="M0,2.3629998L11.63953,2.3629998 9.1447105,4.8564929 2.4934592,4.8564929 2.4934592,14.710437 12.712251,14.710437 12.712251,8.4683789 15.206,5.9748863 15.206,17.204 0,17.204z M11.741774,0L17.591398,0 17.591999,5.8514608 15.648591,3.9075235 7.7964079,11.759001 5.8289994,9.7914637 13.681183,1.9400271z" Padding="13,10,10,15" Margin="20,0" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FFE6E6E6"/>

        </StackPanel>
        <Slider Name="timelineSlider" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,20,10,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="00:0 / 00:0" FontSize="18" Margin="20,0,20,40" Foreground="White"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // You should use the MediaElement.IsFullWindow property instead
    // to enable and disable full window rendering.
    private bool _isFullscreenToggle = false;
    public bool IsFullscreen
    {
        get { return _isFullscreenToggle; }
        set { _isFullscreenToggle = value; }
    }

    private Size _previousVideoContainerSize = new Size();

    private async void FullscreenToggle()
    {
        this.IsFullscreen = !this.IsFullscreen;

        if (this.IsFullscreen)
        {
            //TransportControlsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync(); 
            DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape | DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped;
            _previousVideoContainerSize.Width = videoContainer.ActualWidth;
            _previousVideoContainerSize.Height = videoContainer.ActualHeight;

            videoContainer.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
            videoContainer.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            videoMediaElement.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
            videoMediaElement.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            // Trigger the Visual State Manager
            //VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Landscape", false);
        }
        else
        {
            //TransportControlsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ShowAsync(); 
            DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.None;
            videoContainer.Width = _previousVideoContainerSize.Width;
            videoContainer.Height = _previousVideoContainerSize.Height;
            videoMediaElement.Width = _previousVideoContainerSize.Width;
            videoMediaElement.Height = _previousVideoContainerSize.Height;
            // Trigger the Visual State Manager
            //VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Portrait",false);
        }
    }

    private void btnFullScreenToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FullscreenToggle();
    }

    private void VideoContainer_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsFullscreen && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Escape)
        {
            FullscreenToggle();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate != 1)
        {
            videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate = 1.0;
        }
        if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Pause();
            Play1.Content = "M0,0L384.885,191.965 769.768,383.928 384.885,576.035 0,768 0,383.928z"; // Play
            Play1.Padding = new Thickness(19, 5, 12, 5);
        }
        else if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Play();
            Play1.Content = "M27.270001,0L44.310001,0 44.310001,48.643002 27.270001,48.643002z M0,0L17.040001,0 17.040001,48.643002 0,48.643002z";
            Play1.Padding = new Thickness(20, 10, 20, 10);
        }
    }

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public void Start_timer()
    {
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(00, 0, 5);
        bool enabled = timer.IsEnabled;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        //function to execute
        if (TransportControlsPanel.Visibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible)
        {
            TransportControlsPanel.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.Pause();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.Stop();
    }

    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate = 2.0;
        videoMediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void btnReverse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double Int1 = videoMediaElement.Position.TotalSeconds - 10;
        if (Int1 > 0)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(videoMediaElement.Position.TotalSeconds - 10);
            videoMediaElement.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            videoMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
            videoMediaElement.Play();
        }
    }

    private void btnVolumeDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.IsMuted)
        {
            videoMediaElement.IsMuted = false;
        }

        if (videoMediaElement.Volume < 1)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Volume += .1;
        }
    }

    private void btnMute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.IsMuted = !videoMediaElement.IsMuted;
    }

    private void btnVolumeUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.IsMuted)
        {
            videoMediaElement.IsMuted = false;
        }

        if (videoMediaElement.Volume > 0)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Volume -= .1;
        }
    }

    private void cbAudioTracks_SelectionChanged(
        object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //videoMediaElement.AudioStreamIndex = cbAudioTracks.SelectedIndex;
    }

    private void PopulateAudioTracks(
        MediaElement media, ComboBox audioSelection)
    {
        if (media.AudioStreamCount > 0)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < media.AudioStreamCount; index++)
            {
                ComboBoxItem track = new ComboBoxItem();
                track.Content = media.GetAudioStreamLanguage(index);
                audioSelection.Items.Add(track);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timelineSlider.ValueChanged += timelineSlider_ValueChanged;

        PointerEventHandler pointerpressedhandler = new PointerEventHandler(slider_PointerEntered);
        timelineSlider.AddHandler(Control.PointerPressedEvent, pointerpressedhandler, true);

        PointerEventHandler pointerreleasedhandler = new PointerEventHandler(slider_PointerCaptureLost);
        timelineSlider.AddHandler(Control.PointerCaptureLostEvent, pointerreleasedhandler, true);
    }

    void videoElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double absvalue = (int)Math.Round(
            videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds,
            MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        timelineSlider.Maximum = absvalue;

        timelineSlider.StepFrequency =
            SliderFrequency(videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan);

        SetupTimer();

        // Helper method to populate the combobox with audio tracks.
        //PopulateAudioTracks(videoMediaElement, cbAudioTracks);
    }

    private bool _sliderpressed = false;

    void slider_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _sliderpressed = true;
    }

    void slider_PointerCaptureLost(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timelineSlider.Value);
        _sliderpressed = false;
    }

    void timelineSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_sliderpressed)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    void videoMediaElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            Play1.Content = "M27.270001,0L44.310001,0 44.310001,48.643002 27.270001,48.643002z M0,0L17.040001,0 17.040001,48.643002 0,48.643002z";
            Play1.Padding = new Thickness(20, 10, 20, 10);
            if (_sliderpressed)
            {
                _timer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                _timer.Start();
            }
        }

        if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
        {
            Play1.Content = "M0,0L384.885,191.965 769.768,383.928 384.885,576.035 0,768 0,383.928z"; // Play
            Play1.Padding = new Thickness(19, 5, 12, 5);
            _timer.Stop();
        }

        if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            timelineSlider.Value = 0;
        }
    }

    void videoMediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopTimer();
        timelineSlider.Value = 0.0;
    }

    private void videoMediaElement_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get HRESULT from event args 
        string hr = GetHresultFromErrorMessage(e);

        // Handle media failed event appropriately 
    }

    private string GetHresultFromErrorMessage(ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String hr = String.Empty;
        String token = "HRESULT - ";
        const int hrLength = 10;     // eg "0xFFFFFFFF"

        int tokenPos = e.ErrorMessage.IndexOf(token, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (tokenPos != -1)
        {
            hr = e.ErrorMessage.Substring(tokenPos + token.Length, hrLength);
        }

        return hr;
    }

    private DispatcherTimer _timer;

    private void SetupTimer()
    {
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        StartTimer();
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (!_sliderpressed)
        {
            timelineSlider.Value = videoMediaElement.Position.TotalSeconds;
            TimeSpan TS = new TimeSpan(videoMediaElement.Position.Hours, videoMediaElement.Position.Minutes, videoMediaElement.Position.Seconds);
            TimeSpan TS1 = new TimeSpan(videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Hours, videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Minutes, videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Seconds);
            TextBlock1.Text = TS.Duration().ToString("c") + " / " + TS1.Duration().ToString("c");
        }
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Tick -= _timer_Tick;
    }

    private double SliderFrequency(TimeSpan timevalue)
    {
        double stepfrequency = -1;

        double absvalue = (int)Math.Round(
            timevalue.TotalSeconds, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        stepfrequency = (int)(Math.Round(absvalue / 100));

        if (timevalue.TotalMinutes >= 10 && timevalue.TotalMinutes < 30)
        {
            stepfrequency = 10;
        }
        else if (timevalue.TotalMinutes >= 30 && timevalue.TotalMinutes < 60)
        {
            stepfrequency = 30;
        }
        else if (timevalue.TotalHours >= 1)
        {
            stepfrequency = 60;
        }

        if (stepfrequency == 0) stepfrequency += 1;

        if (stepfrequency == 1)
        {
            stepfrequency = absvalue / 100;
        }

        return stepfrequency;
    }

    private void videoMediaElement_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TransportControlsPanel.Visibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible)
        {
            TransportControlsPanel.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            timer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            TransportControlsPanel.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
            Start_timer();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time try to give you code, show what you did this way it's easier to help.

Did you saw the page on msdn that explain how to do a custom media player control ?

[How to create custom media transport controls (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh986967.aspx)

You mentioned *AreTransportControlsEnabled*  and I don't think it's laggy, remember that if you try on the simulator, it's a VM that runs Windows Phone so if you don't have a very powerfull computer you can see some lags that you won't see on a Nokia 930 for example.

But if you still want to make it custom, I think you can start from the code given by Msdn.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MediaPlayerQuickStart.MainPage"
    IsTabStop="false"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MediaPlayerQuickStart"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Loaded="MainPage_Loaded"> 

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Name="transportStyle"  TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ContentControl x:Name="videoContainer" 
                            KeyUp="VideoContainer_KeyUp" 
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                            Height="400" Grid.Row="0" >
                <MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement"
                              Source="Media/video1.mp4" 
                              MediaOpened="videoElement_MediaOpened" 
                              MediaEnded="videoMediaElement_MediaEnded" 
                              MediaFailed="videoMediaElement_MediaFailed"
                              CurrentStateChanged="videoMediaElement_CurrentStateChanged"
                              PosterSource="Media/Video1_Poster.png"
                              AutoPlay="False" />
            </ContentControl>
            <!-- Transport Controls -->
        <StackPanel Name="TransportControlsPanel" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Grid.Row="1" >
            <Slider Name="timelineSlider" Margin="10,0" Width="200"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Name="btnPlay" Click="btnPlay_Click" 
                        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Play" />
                <Button Name="btnPause" Click="btnPause_Click"
                        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Pause" />
                <Button Name="btnStop" Click="btnStop_Click"
                        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Stop" />
                <Button Name="btnReverse" Click="btnReverse_Click"
                        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Rewind" />
                <Button Name="btnForward" Click="btnForward_Click"
                        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Forward" />
                <Button Name="btnMute" Click="btnMute_Click" 
                        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Mute" />
                <Button Name="btnFullScreenToggle" Click="btnFullScreenToggle_Click" 
                        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Full" />
                <ComboBox Name="cbAudioTracks"
                          SelectionChanged="cbAudioTracks_SelectionChanged" 
                          Width="75" />
                <Button Name="btnVolumeUp" Click="btnVolumeUp_Click" 
                        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="-" />
                <Button Name="btnVolumeDown" Click="btnVolumeDown_Click" 
                        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="+" />
                <TextBlock Name="txtVolume" FontSize="14"
                           Text="{Binding Volume, ElementName=videoMediaElement}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // You should use the MediaElement.IsFullWindow property instead
    // to enable and disable full window rendering.
    private bool _isFullscreenToggle = false;
    public bool IsFullscreen
    {
        get { return _isFullscreenToggle; }
        set { _isFullscreenToggle = value; }
    }

    private Size _previousVideoContainerSize = new Size();

    private void FullscreenToggle()
    {
        this.IsFullscreen = !this.IsFullscreen;

        if (this.IsFullscreen)
        {    
            TransportControlsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            _previousVideoContainerSize.Width = videoContainer.ActualWidth;
            _previousVideoContainerSize.Height = videoContainer.ActualHeight;

            videoContainer.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
            videoContainer.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            videoMediaElement.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
            videoMediaElement.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            TransportControlsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            videoContainer.Width = _previousVideoContainerSize.Width;
            videoContainer.Height = _previousVideoContainerSize.Height;
            videoMediaElement.Width = _previousVideoContainerSize.Width;
            videoMediaElement.Height = _previousVideoContainerSize.Height;
        }
    }

    private void btnFullScreenToggle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FullscreenToggle();
    }

    private void VideoContainer_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsFullscreen && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Escape)
        {
            FullscreenToggle();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate != 1)
        {
            videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate = 1.0;
        }

        videoMediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            videoMediaElement.Pause();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.Stop();
    }

    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate = 2.0;
        videoMediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void btnReverse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate = -2;
        videoMediaElement.Play();;
    }

    private void btnVolumeDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.IsMuted)
        {
            videoMediaElement.IsMuted = false;
        }

        if (videoMediaElement.Volume < 1)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Volume += .1;
        }
    }

    private void btnMute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.IsMuted = !videoMediaElement.IsMuted;
    }

    private void btnVolumeUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.IsMuted)
        {
            videoMediaElement.IsMuted = false;
        }

        if (videoMediaElement.Volume > 0)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Volume -= .1;
        }
    }

    private void cbAudioTracks_SelectionChanged(
        object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.AudioStreamIndex = cbAudioTracks.SelectedIndex;
    }

    private void PopulateAudioTracks(
        MediaElement media, ComboBox audioSelection)
    {
        if (media.AudioStreamCount > 0)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < media.AudioStreamCount; index++)
            {
                ComboBoxItem track = new ComboBoxItem();
                track.Content = media.GetAudioStreamLanguage(index);
                audioSelection.Items.Add(track);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timelineSlider.ValueChanged += timelineSlider_ValueChanged;

        PointerEventHandler pointerpressedhandler = new PointerEventHandler(slider_PointerEntered);
        timelineSlider.AddHandler(Control.PointerPressedEvent, pointerpressedhandler, true);

        PointerEventHandler pointerreleasedhandler = new PointerEventHandler(slider_PointerCaptureLost);
        timelineSlider.AddHandler(Control.PointerCaptureLostEvent, pointerreleasedhandler, true);
    }

    void videoElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double absvalue = (int)Math.Round(
            videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds,
            MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        timelineSlider.Maximum = absvalue;

        timelineSlider.StepFrequency =
            SliderFrequency(videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan);

        SetupTimer();

        // Helper method to populate the combobox with audio tracks.
        PopulateAudioTracks(videoMediaElement, cbAudioTracks);
    }

    private bool _sliderpressed = false;

    void slider_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _sliderpressed = true;
    }

    void slider_PointerCaptureLost(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        videoMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timelineSlider.Value);
        _sliderpressed = false;
    }

    void timelineSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_sliderpressed)
        {
            videoMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    void videoMediaElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            if (_sliderpressed)
            {
                _timer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                _timer.Start();
            }
        }

        if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }

        if (videoMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            timelineSlider.Value = 0;
        }
    }

    void videoMediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopTimer();
        timelineSlider.Value = 0.0;
    }

    private void videoMediaElement_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get HRESULT from event args 
        string hr = GetHresultFromErrorMessage(e);

        // Handle media failed event appropriately 
    }

    private string GetHresultFromErrorMessage(ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String hr = String.Empty;
        String token = "HRESULT - ";
        const int hrLength = 10;     // eg "0xFFFFFFFF"

        int tokenPos = e.ErrorMessage.IndexOf(token, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (tokenPos != -1)
        {
            hr = e.ErrorMessage.Substring(tokenPos + token.Length, hrLength);
        }

        return hr;
    }

    private DispatcherTimer _timer;

    private void SetupTimer()
    {
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timelineSlider.StepFrequency);
        StartTimer();
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (!_sliderpressed)
        {
            timelineSlider.Value = videoMediaElement.Position.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Tick -= _timer_Tick;
    }

    private double SliderFrequency(TimeSpan timevalue)
    {
        double stepfrequency = -1;

        double absvalue = (int)Math.Round(
            timevalue.TotalSeconds, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        stepfrequency = (int)(Math.Round(absvalue / 100));

        if (timevalue.TotalMinutes >= 10 && timevalue.TotalMinutes < 30)
        {
            stepfrequency = 10;
        }
        else if (timevalue.TotalMinutes >= 30 && timevalue.TotalMinutes < 60)
        {
            stepfrequency = 30;
        }
        else if (timevalue.TotalHours >= 1)
        {
            stepfrequency = 60;
        }

        if (stepfrequency == 0) stepfrequency += 1;

        if (stepfrequency == 1)
        {
            stepfrequency = absvalue / 100;
        }

        return stepfrequency;
    }
}
```

If you want to change the look of the buttons you can use AppBarButton instead of normal buttons (give them the round windows8 like look)

To change the behavior for fullscreen, look at **FullscreenToggle()**. In this example they collapse the StackPanel with the controls but you don't have to and can implement your own logic.